# PDF convert issue with QPDF

Tags: java, linux, jsp, pdf

I am converting a PDF file using QPDF , this pdf file is uploaded by a jsp page ,
this is my command (in Ubuntu)
    'qpdf --qdf ~/apache-tomcat-7.0.22/bin/733000.pdf /tmp/testP.pdf'

when i run this  it says :
      ~/apache-tomcat-7.0.22/bin/733000.pdf: not a PDF file
but
when i run this command to same PDF file without upload it , then there is no error

I'am using QPDF version 2.2.2
What can be the reason  ?

Thanks

Comment: manually running this command on a terminal??? else, try to use some absolute path instead of wildcards

Comment: yes , i am running manually on a terminal ,  also i tried using absolute paths , but same result.

Comment: when i cat both uploaded and original PDFs, i can see the 'Content-Disposition' and 'Content-Type' is there at uploaded file , that is the only different i can see with comparing to original one.Can It be a reason ? , Is there any way to remove those lines before save the uploaded file ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As from the comments, let me propose an answer for you.

The file in the temporary location is not the exact file you upload. Are you doing the `fileItem.write(fileOb)` in the servlet you handle upload?. May be you can just have a look at this link, and find out how they handle this condition.
http://www.tutorialspoint.com/servlets/servlets-file-uploading.htm 
If it was not done properly, the source file is corrupted as we look from point of a PDF handler.
EDIT:

Also as an alternative , try using [Apache Commons File Upload](http://commons.apache.org/fileupload/streaming.html)

Thanks

Comment: thank you very much Krishnanunni ,  commons file uploader fixed the issue , its not writing 'Content-Disposition' and 'Content-Type' to the uploaded file , thanks again